# Recommended Library/Macro that Deletes Installed Files on Uninstallation

Tags: installation, nsis

Which library or macro that deletes only installed files when the uninstallation is run would you recommend?

I'm aware this kind question has been asked alot but I'm looking for advice on the most current and easiest to use macro/library. As in the past,I used old macros that were posted on [NSIS Website](http://nsis.sourceforge.net) for things like Command Line Argument parsing and had problems with the code and implementation.

My understanding is that there are 2 so far(are there more?):

[Advanced_Uninstall_Log](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Advanced_Uninstall_Log_NSIS_Header)
[Uninstall_only_installed_files](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files)

Which library or single macro do you use and recommend?

I am hoping that I am able to install files by only specifying a folder X(and all its sub files will be installed) and the uninstaller will then delete all the subfiles in folder X but leave any the user created.

For eg:

```
Section "install"
   File \r "FolderX" 

   # note how I dont do this..
   File \r "FolderX\filea.txt" 
   File \r "FolderX\fileb.txt"
SectionEnd

Section "un.uninstall"
   ${RemoveDir} "FolderX" 

   # The above hypothetical function will hopefully only delete the files in FolderX that I installed.
   Delete \r "FolderX\filea.txt" 
   Delete \r "FolderX\fileb.txt"
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both of the above mentioned, and neither worked for me. The Advanced_Uninstall_Log worked well, but for the amount of data I had it added a huge delay during the install.

The uninstall_only_installed_files isn't for doing recursive install with file /r.

I ended up writing a python script that created two macros, InstallFiles and UninstallFiles. I use a batch file to call this script and generate an install_files.nsh prior to building the NSIS installer with MakeNSIS.

Someone posted his similar script here; http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Talk:Uninstall_only_installed_files