# How to delete files created with *

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm creating an installer with NSIS which will install more than 100 files.

I know that to specify which files you want to install you can use

```
File /r ..\release\*
```

Which works very well.

But what should I do to uninstall these files ( Appart from using the Delete command individually for each file that I know that is installed. )

I've taken a look on RMDir which doesn't seem really safe to use. And also [here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Uninstall_only_installed_files) which didn't work.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Relevant:http://stackoverflow.com/q/16270931/656243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RMDir` is safe. It's use of the `/r` flag that the doc warns about:

> Warning: using RMDir /r $INSTDIR in the uninstaller is not safe.
>   Though it is unlikely, the user might select to install to the Program
>   Files folder and so this command will wipe out the entire Program
>   Files folder, including other programs that has nothing to do with the
>   uninstaller. The user can also put other files but the program's files
>   and would expect them to get deleted with the program. Solutions are
>   available for easily uninstalling only files which were installed by
>   the installer

Given this, I'd think you'd just manually remove any subdirectories, then delete the parent. The only case that I can think of where this wouldn't work is when your application is generating new folders dynamically. And if that's the case, even the uninstall log isn't going to help you there.

It's also perfectly okay to use /r on a subdirectory that you created. The concern is deletion of the top-level install directory, and everything that may have existed in it. If your installer rolls out a folder with additional assets called `images`, which also contains subdirectories, there's no reason why

```
RMDir /r $INSTDIR\images`
```

would be dangerous.